# How to switch datasources in loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, loopback4

I have a loopback 4 application that uses a mysql db as the datasource. It is created like

```
export class ES {
  public readonly app: express.Application;
  public readonly myApp: myApplication;
  private server?: http.Server;

....
}
```

I would like to switch the datasource to an in memory datasource when testing, so I tried

```
export async function setupEAWithInMemoryDb(): Promise<AWC> {

  const testdb: juggler.DataSource = new juggler.DataSource({
    name: 'db',
    connector: 'memory',
  });

  const server = new ES({rest: givenHttpServerConfig()});
  await server.boot();
  const myApp = server.myApp;

  myApp.dataSource(testdb);
  
  await server.start();

  const client = supertest(server.app);

  return {server, client, myApp};
}

export interface AWC {
  server: ES;
  client: Client;
  myApp: MyApplication;
}
```

but the datasource doesnt switch (it keeps using the original datasource). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I did this kind of thing by defining alternate config objects in my .datasource.ts file ( in my case one config for when the app is running on linux and one for android) and then using code like this:

```
constructor(
@inject('datasources.config.db', {optional: true})
dsConfig: any = process.platform === 'linux' ? linuxconfig : androidconfig) {
```